# How it is possible in Java for false to equal true

Tags: java, boolean

In this program, how can false be equal to true:

```
public class Wow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if ( false == true ){ // \u000a\u007d\u007b
            System.out.println("How is it possible!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with `// \u000a\u007d\u007b` :|

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - It has everything to do with that. Editing the question to remove the comment is an invalid edit.

Comment: Don't be shy...tell us...is this homework?

Comment: This is not a bad question to downvoted (5), rather this would tell you to be careful when including unicode chars even as a comment

Comment: Now answer makes sense, without that comment in question I was scratching my head on @TedHopp answer.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Ah. It was Quillion who made the invalid edit. I read the edit history wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: It is suggested to edit the question with removed comment - for future use

Comment: Whoa.  Curious, does C# do anything like this?

Comment: @AdamRackis - According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), C# is much more selective about escape sequence processing: _Unicode character escape sequences are processed in identifiers, character literals , and regular string literals. A Unicode character escape is not processed in any other location (for example, to form an operator, punctuator, or keyword)._

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Well, I'll be generous and assume that this question was asked out of innocence.

The Java compiler parses Unicode escape sequences very early in the process. In particular, it does this before stripping comments or checking for syntax. Since `\u000a` is a newline, `\u007d` is the character "}" and `\u007b` is the character "{", the parser is actually parsing this program:

```
public class Wow{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if ( false == true ){ // 
}{
            System.out.println("How is it possible!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

This program will always print the "impossible" output.

Answer (score 1):

I was just experimenting this question,(answer as well) , and found interesting behavior

```
public class TestUniCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(" Printing first line");
        // \u000a\u007d\u007b
        System.out.println(" Printing second line");
    }
}
```

And very surprisingly (for me) it only prints `Printing first line`, and ignores the second line

**EDIT**  - I understood, it closing the main method after first line and the second line will be outside main as  separate block

Comment: Yep. The second line becomes the body of an instance initializer. It would run each time you created an instance of `TestUniCode`.